# How to change the navigation bar font and color of the text?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried everything (**Bootstrap4**) and couldn't :

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right  li a {
    color: green;
}
```

Will not work.

The nav bar list is as follow :

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Home</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Create</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
```

Also couldn't change the font.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are keeping the above code enclosed in  tag. You can use the given css.

```
nav.navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a {
color: green;
font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the code like this, I have made working example kindly see it https://www.bootply.com/fOgwVUAbzr

**Html:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Create</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-nav li a {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Why should I change my code to this? because it works? but i wonder what is wrong with mine..

Comment: @Curnelious, In your code many thing is missing, Navbar needs to have like this ```<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">``` and you have added the following ```.nav``` and ```.navbar-right``` in your css but there is no such class in your html..